# Enabling the User to Insert the Data in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have created a data model in Access Database. 
Tables that are composite parts of the model are loaded with data. Some of the data needs to be loaded manually.

Now I would like to link couple of tables together and give the user the option to insert the missing data in the tables. (I am linking the tables together so that the user doesn't have to work with raw keys, but with the "actual" information that he knows.)

I+ve never worked with Access DB before and therefore I would like to ask you to please instruct and help me on how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

The access form wizards are pretty well put together. You can easily setup a form that will allow them to insert data into the table(s).

Comment: Subforms can be useful as well and are often ignored by people new to MS Access. It is also a good idea to look at the various templates to see how forms can be put together.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've made a form and I can edit the individual rows. But what I can't do is add new rows. Can you give me some suggestion please?

Comment: You need to "Allow Additions" for the form but by default this is usually enabled. Another problem could be that the table you are working with has requirements that aren't being met (like records in an associated table). As @Remou mentioned subforms are great for that. Without knowing more about what you are doing it is difficult to give you more focused suggestions.

Comment: @Dantes It is possible that this is to do with your recordset rather than your form. Did you create a query or just use the wizards? What does the form's record source say (property sheet)?